# What's the most reliable tool to backup all the drivers of a Windows 10 tablet 2 in 1?

Tags: windows-10, backup, device-driver, tablet

I'm about to do a fresh install of Windows 10 on a cheapo 2 in 1 tablet and I'm pretty sure finding the appropriate drivers later would be a major pain because it's not a standard device. So I want to backup what's already installed and working right now so i can restore it cleanly later after the re-install is finished.

I'm also making a full image with Macrium Reflect.

Comment: Have you tried "Windows Backup" from the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From and administrative command prompt:

pnputil /export-driver * c:\backup      <- Export all driver packages

Directly from pnputil /?

Backing up C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository

can also be done, but its all drivers including ALL the microsoft drivers and possibly all version of drivers even old ones that haven't been uninstalled.

Restore the drivers:

```
pnputil /add-driver c:\drivers\*.inf /install <- Add and install driver package
```

Sadly, you may have to script the above since I don't think it automatically recurses through sub-directories.

You can also go through the device manager one at a time, but that is too cumbersome.

```
dism /image:c: /Add-Driver /driver:c:\drivers /recurse
```

Sadly this can only be done to an offline copy of windows, like boot from the Windows DVD,usb, or etc and goto command prompt.

Something like this:

```
@for /R c:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ %i in (*.inf); do pnputil /add-driver "%i" /install
```

Change the path to where ever your drivers are located.

Comment: How do i install it later?

Comment: @user9564371  Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can export all this drivers with `DISM`: *The Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)* the command-line tool used for managing Windows images and components.

```
 mkdir .\DriversBackup
 DISM /online /export-driver /destination:.\DriversBackup
```